# Laravel PDOException SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] occurs suddenly at runtime

Tags: mysql, database, exception, pdo, laravel-5

In our Laravel app we've built an installer which asks for database information from user to run our database migration and seeder. The fields we are asking from user:

- DB type
- DB name
- DB host
- DB user
- DB password

We are writing this values in .env file while in installation process

```
DB_TYPE={value entered by user}
DB_HOST={value entered by user}
DB_PORT={value entered by user}
DB_DATABASE={value entered by user}
DB_USERNAME={value entered by user}
DB_PASSWORD={value entered by user}
```

In our database.php cofig file we are retrieving environment values from .env

sample code of datatbase.php for mysql

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'port'      => env('DB_PORT', ''),
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
```

We are not facing any issue in the installation process and database connection runs successfully. But after using application for some time this PDOException occurs randomly for random routes

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
>
> SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Please tell me What is the possible reason for that and how can we solve this problem.

TIA

Comment: looks like some of the processes do not read .env file...

Comment: @Jerzyk can you suggest how can we prevent this, and force all processes to read .env file.